# What exactly does `iwconfig wlan1 essid "myWifi"` do?

Tags: networking, dhclient, iw

I'm working on an embedded device with a limited amount of programs for managing the network.

I ended up using the command:

```
iwconfig wlan1 essid "myWifi" key "s:password"
```

At times this works but I have to run `dhclient wlan1` after.

Can someone break down this `iwconfig` command?

It seems that running the command above doesn't actually cause my interface to make a connection. It just tells it what to connect to when it does connect?

Also how should I go about logging the results of using this command?

---

*Edit: [this seems to be the source](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools) (though the [version doesn't seem up to date](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/issues/5))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
iwconfig wlan1 essid "myWifi" key "s:password"
```

will associate the wifi device with the Access Point

The command :

```
dhclient wlan1
```

is used to get an IP address through DHCP

You can assign an IP address manually (without using `dhclient` command):

```
ifconfig wlan1  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```